# Django clean-up code

Tags: python, django, resource-cleanup

In my `models.py` I open some files and database connections. Where can I place code to ensure that these files/connections are closed when the server shuts down?

Comment: If the server shuts down, everything is closed. Closing files/connections only matters if the application is still running.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Still it would be nice to have some control over things - perhaps being able to flush to disk before exiting?

Comment: Why and how are you opening files/dbconnections, some sample code/example will be helpful

Comment: If you shutdown the server, SIGTERM signals are issued to all running processes (and eventually SIGKILL if they've taken too long to terminate). But, the running process is your webserver or such, not Django itself.

Comment: @AnuragUniyal I have a pytables connection and a mongodb connection that are both opened in `models.py` - I'm not so fussed about mongo but I'd be happier if I could call pytables flush() commands before exiting.

Comment: @ChrisPratt sorry I don't mean the whole webserver, I just mean the django/python process.

Answer (score 0):

You could use python's *with* statement. This lets your code tidy up after itself. I.e. files are closed.

Here is a good tutorial: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: Would do normally, but don't see how I can use that in this case. Basically a connection is opened when django starts up (in models.py) and then interacted with by html POST commands.